# looking for a proverb regarding defeat of man

Tags: idioms

There is a saying in my local language, Urdu, which loosely translates to "*Man tastes the defeat always from his favorite woman.*" in English. Is there any proper idiom for it in English?

The saying itself in its original form is :
"مرد کو شکست ہمیشہ اپنی من پسند عورت سے ہوتی ہے"

Comment: I have heard a similar saying _it takes a woman to break a man_ which, I assume, has a similar meaning.

Comment: ITExpert, what is your Native Language? If you're trying to translate an idiom, we may be better able to help you with the translation if we know the original language and the term in said language. Additionally, add the "Translation" tag. It will get you help from more capable people.

Comment: @SoraTamashii question updated as per your suggestions.

Comment: Looking at the saying and comparing the words and comparative meaning, while it's not an exact 1-for-1, Nigel J's answer is the closest English equivalent. The issue is, Nigel's answer can be taken a couple ways. If used as-is, it can mean both "a man's greatest weakness is the woman he loves" and it can mean "In order to get a man to break (like a horse) it takes a woman, not just some girl." I've heard it in both contexts. I'll see if I can build a better translation, but that may be your answer. (If I fail to make a better answer, I won't submit anything as an answer.)

Comment: @SoraTamashii Your comment here, using NigelJ's saying, is the basis for a really useful answer! I encourage you to develop it as such, even at this late stage. I think it would add significantly to our site's "library of great answers" :-)

Answer (score 3):

**"It's the things we love most that destroy us."**

I don't know the original source of this, but a quick Google search shows that it was used in Game of Thrones:

> "The things we love destroy us every time, lad. Remember that."

[(Source)](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/7498137-it-s-the-things-we-love-most-that-destroy-us)

And in Hunger Games:

> "It's the things we love most, that destroy us."

[(Source)](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/7498137-it-s-the-things-we-love-most-that-destroy-us)

My guess is that the saying is older than those books though.

Comment: But the saying I shared specifically focuses on woman.

Comment: @ITExpert Can you use your expression for things not related to a woman? In other words is the use of "woman" metaphoric? Or is the expression only used for women? Say for example a race car driver who is killed in a race, can it be used for that? Or do you want a direct translation from the Urdu to English? If so I think that's off topic.

Comment: I was ambivalent about this answer, only because I didn't find it in an authoritative dictionary or book of proverbs/sayings. But it is a saying, and I like it, so I've upvoted.

Comment: +1 @ITExpert Idioms are not meant to be taken literally word for word. To me, the meaning of this and your original phrase are essentially the same. (It's the use of "his favourite" that implies "things we care about most".)

Comment: I have updated the question title as it appears that I was looking for a proverb, rather than an idiom.